# Modify parameters in Objective-C blocks

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I would like to modify various variables which exist outside an Objective-C block within it's body.

I know I can directly access and modify a variable using the `__block` attribute while declaring the variable. So this works:

```
__block NSMutableString *alertMessage;

void(^appendMessage)(NSMutableString*, NSString*)= ^(NSString *append){

    if (!alertMessage)
    {
        alertMessage = [NSMutableString new];
    }

    if ([append length] > 0)
    {
        [alertMessage appendString:@"\n"];
    }

    [alertMessage appendString:append];
};

appendMessage(@"Alert part 1"); //This works fine
```

However I want to create a block which can perform an operation on a passed variable, enabling me to use the operation on multiple variables outside the block without directly accessing the same. Something like the following:

```
__block NSMutableString *alertMessage;
__block NSMutableString *otherString;

void(^appendMessage)(NSMutableString*, NSString*)= ^(NSMutableString *string, NSString *append){

    if (!string)
    {
        string = [NSMutableString new];
    }

    if ([append length] > 0)
    {
        [string appendString:@"\n"];
    }

    [string appendString:append];
};

//The following do not work as intended
appendMessage(alertMessage, @"Alert Part 1"); 
appendMessage(otherString, @"Bleh bleh");
```

I want to be able to use the above block to modify the variables declared before it.

How can I achieve such an operation? Is this even possible?

Comment: You could just create a C function that does the same. Why do you want to use a block for this purpose?

Comment: @WolfgangSchreurs The operation as specified in the block is required within a particular function. While a C function would indeed do the trick (or an Objective-C one for that matter) declaring the same operation within a block would have the additional benefit of isolating the code for use within the function as well as making the same more readable.

Comment: why can't you initialise the parameter before (outside) the block, it's the only thing causing you the 'issue'

Comment: @Wain I would like to have the option of the variables being nil. Yeah, I could simply check for their lengths afterwards... This is not as clean as I would hope. Thanks! It's evident now that this cannot be achieved as desired. Nice to know for academic purposes.

Comment: @WolfgangSchreurs Thanks. I will use another approach.

Comment: i guess you can pass a pointer to the pointer, i haven't tried before with blocks

Answer (score 2):

Your question shows some confusion over values and variables, maybe the following will help.

> Modify parameters in Objective-C blocks

In (Objective-)C all parameters to methods/functions/blocks are passed by *value*, e.g. when in the call `f(x)` the value of the variable `x` is passed to `f`, not the variable itself. This is known as *call-by-value*.

There are languages which do allow *variables* to be passed, known as *call-by-reference*. When used the argument must be a variable and the parameter name within the function is effectively an *alias* to the supplied variable. This is not supported directly in (Objective-)C.

However you can *emulate* it in (Objective-)C. It is not commonly used, with one notable exception: many methods use it to return an `NSError *` value.

You later comment:

> What I want to achieve includes object creation, which is essentially what the question now boils down to. "Can I create an object declared outside within a block?". The answer which I have gathered with the help of all the activity here is NO.

You can, it is just a question of whether you should (i.e. is the design right?) and the best way to do it.

The straightforward way to solve your particular issue is to write a *function*:

```
NSMutableString *alertMessage;
NSMutableString *otherString;

NSMutableString *(^appendMessage)(NSMutableString *, NSString *) =
   ^(NSMutableString *string, NSString *append)
   {
      if (!string)
         string = [NSMutableString new];

      if (append.length > 0)
      {
         [string appendString:@"\n"];
         [string appendString:append];
      }

      return string;
   };

alertMessage = appendMessage(alertMessage, @"Alert Part 1");
otherString = appendMessage(otherString, @"Bleh bleh");
```

If you *really* (*really, really*) want to you can instead "pass the variable" by passing its *address* (using the `&` operator) and *indirection* (using the `*` operator) inside the block to get/set the value:

```
void (^appendMessage)(NSMutableString **, NSString *) =
   ^(NSMutableString **stringPtr, NSString *append)
   {
      if (!stringPtr) return; // no "variable" passed

      NSMutableString *string = *stringPtr; // use indirection to get the value in the passed variable

      if (!string)
         string = [NSMutableString new];

      if (append.length > 0)
      {
         [string appendString:@"\n"];
         [string appendString:append];
      }

      *stringPtr = string; // use indirection to set the passed variable
   };


appendMessage(&alertMessage, @"Alert Part 1"); // pass "variable" by passing its address
appendMessage(&otherString, @"Bleh bleh");
```

While the above is valid code it is generally not recommended coding practice in Objective-C for simple cases such as yours.

> Once you take the address of a variable you need to be concerned over the *lifetime* of that variable - if you attempt to use the address to access the variable after the variable has been destroyed your program will fail (the *dangling pointer problem*)

**What about `__block`?**

Neither of the above examples use `__block` anywhere.

When a block references a variable by default it captures the variables *value* at the time the block is created. The `__block` attribute changes this to capturing the *variable* (so its value can be changed by the block) and alters the *lifetime* of the capture variable if required (so the variable lives at least as long as the capturing block, avoiding the dangling pointer problem).

The `__block` attribute is not applicable in your situation as you wish to capture *different* variables based on the call.

HTH

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The code, as written, seems to confuse *operation on object* with *object creation*.

For clarity's sake, you should either pass in a mutable object to be manipulated *or* you should define a single `__block` variable whose value will be set by the block (and you do the logic after to figure out where that value should be stuffed).

Passing in something by reference is inherently dangerous to the point of being an anti-pattern (what happens as soon as you try to refactor the code to be asynchronous?  At least in the `__block` case, the code after the block will see `nil`).

i.e.:

```
__block NSMutableString *foo = [sourceString mutableCopy];
doIt(@"new stuff"); // appends to `foo`
whereItShouldReallyGo = foo;
```

Comment: What I want to achieve includes object creation, which is essentially what the question now boils down to. "Can I create an object declared outside within a block?". The answer which I have gathered with the help of all the activity here is NO. Thanks!